# SSL/TLS handshake potential vulnerabilities

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, vulnerability, handshake

After `handshake` one could be assure that data are encrypted and secure.

But before that, `handshake` parameters are transferred via not secured channel. One could be `MitM` during the `handshake` procedure.

Why it's not a problem? What actions minimize the threat?

Comment: How TLS and its protection work is explained in depth already in [How does SSL/TLS work](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work). Therefore marked as duplicate.